# Trigger Ribbon menu in Excel online using Typescript

Tags: typescript, ribbon, excel-addins, getelementsbyclassname, excel-online

I am trying to trigger a 3rd party Addin for Excel 365 online using a simple Typescript code written in the Scripts Automate window.

```
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook)
{
  // Your code here
  let element : HTMLElement = document.getElementsByClassName('button.root-415')[0] as HTMLElement;
  element.click();
}
```

But i am getting the following errors:

```
[4, 17] Cannot find name 'HTMLElement'.
[4, 31] Cannot find name 'document'. Do you need to change your target library? Try changing the `lib` compiler option to include 'dom'.
[4, 88] Cannot find name 'HTMLElement'.
```

Can someone help on how to trigger a click event on Excel Ribbon menu to Activate Addin menu and open its Task Pane?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with that script? The `Workbook` interface should include all the controls you need, why are you trying to access a button through `document`?

Answer (score 0):

The error suggests your project's .tsconfig needs to contain the following property in order to include the relevant DOM element and function types:

```json
{
  ...
  "lib": [..., "dom"]
}
```

Edit: You probably don't have access to a .tsconfig from the Excel Automation panel. See my other answer instead.

Comment: How & where do i add line this in Excel online? I am using Script Automate and want to write some Typescript code that will select a 3rd party Addin menu in Ribbon, open it's menu dropdown, make a specific selection in that menu dropdown, then open it's Task Pane. Finally, click a link on the Task pane. I plan to replicate the above code multiple times to each of the above steps. P.S: Its a 3rd party addin, so i dont have its source code.

Comment: The problem is, the above code triggers a click event, only if the Task pane is already open.

Comment: Of course, the element can only be found and clicked if it is currently present in the document. That's not what the errors you posted refer to though. Also, `'button.root-415'` is not a class name so I wouldn't expect the element to be found at all.

Comment: The above document code works only when the 3rd party addin's Task Pane is in open (in focus).

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you're trying to do with your Excel Addin script, manipulating DOM elements is probably the wrong way to go about it.

You can access all kinds of data and functions through the `workbook` object passed to your `main` function. The Workbook Interface is documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office-scripts/excelscript/excelscript.workbook?view=office-scripts).

Comment: The workbook object does not allow access to Ribbon elements to trigger, or to the 3rd party addin Task pane.

Comment: Instead of "clicking" buttons through your script, look for the function the button represents, and call that instead.

Comment: It would be easier to help you if you explained what you're actually trying to achieve.

Comment: There is a 3rd party Addin i have installed in Excel 365 online Ribbon. I am planning to write a script and trigger it every hour (using Microsoft Flow w/o opening Excel workbook) to have it activate the Addin's menu in Ribbon that opens it's task pane, and finally once Taskpane is open, click a link in that Taskpane, to trigger a data refresh in every sheet in Workbook, by looping every sheet (making it Activesheet).

Comment: Right now, the above code is not able to get a handle to the Ribbon menu to click the menu items, inorder to activate the Task pane.

Comment: You've said that three times now. What menu item are you trying to click? What is the "Task pane"? Automation scripts are there to manipulate data, not the UI.

Comment: Thats what i think now. I don't think Automate Scripts can handle UI. When you install an Addin, a menu is added to the Ribbon. I am trying to click the 3rd party Addin Menu and open it's task pane. Then the above code should work fine.

Comment: The Addin when activated, opens up a Task pane in the right hands side of the Excel document. The Taskpane has a link in it, which the above code triggers.